# Does using property names that start with a numeric value in Cosmos DB Table API cause issues?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have just started using Cosmos DB Table API to store data for one of our systems. This system sometimes puts data into columns that start with numeric values.

This doesn't seem to cause any problems in terms of storage or retrieval of the data if you're not trying to filter by the value of that property.

But when you try to filter using that property, the SDK throws an exception.

```
TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("1_Test_Field", QueryComparisons.Equal, "Test")
```

Exception message says "Invalid filter FilterParam=" with an inner exception message of "')' or operator expected at position …"

If I take off the 1_ from the beginning of the property name the exception goes away, which leads me to believe there's a problem with the numeric at the start of the name.

Is there a way around this or will I have to change all the processes that output numeric property names or just not query against them?

Answer (score 2):

The Cosmos DB Table API adheres to Azure Storage Table API contract. Valid property names should follow naming rules for C# identifiers. See [Azure Storage Naming Rules](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2014/06/12/azure-storage-naming-rules/). It should have thrown "The property name is invalid" on insertion. That is a bug which will be fixed soon.